# VHDL, using arithmetic & variables in "downto"?

Tags: vhdl

Quick VHDL question, I don't have access to Xilinx at the moment due to dead laptop, so can't test this.

I was wondering if it's possible to use variables and arithmetic in 'downto' statements, e.g:

```
proc: process (x)
begin
  y <= z(x downto 0) & z(7 downto x);
end process;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, for reference look [this page](http://www.vhdl.org/comp.lang.vhdl/FAQ1.html#const_vectors). Arrays allow integer expressions as a definition of the endpoints of a range.

Comment: Dead link, maybe a new one is available somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it would synthesize to a large and ugly multiplexer instead of a simple shift register which is looks like you are trying to create.